# In github gitflow workflow how to forbid team member to push to central repo master branch?

Tags: git, github, git-flow

In my team , we admit the gitflow workflow.

It works well but has one issue here:
Everyone can push to central repository's master branch.

I want to setup a policy:
People can not push to central repo master branch, they can only launch a 
pull request in github and request the project maintainer to merge their code into master branch if approved by project manager.

How to implement that policy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to implement that policy?

Use a server side hook to prevent it.

Here is a hook code which will do what you are asking for:

#### `pre-receive hook`

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# Check to see if this is the first commit in the repository or not
if git rev-parse --verify HEAD >/dev/null 2>&1
then
    # We compare our changes against the previous commit
    against=HEAD^
else
    # Initial commit: diff against an empty tree object
    against=4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904
fi

# Redirect output to screen.
exec 1>&2

# Check to see if we have updated the master branch
if [ "$refname" eq "refs/heads/master" ];
then

    # Output colors
    red='\033[0;31m';
    green='\033[0;32m';
    yellow='\033[0;33m';
    default='\033[0;m';
    
    # personal touch :-)
    echo "${red}"
    echo "                                         "
    echo "                   |ZZzzz                "
    echo "                   |                     "
    echo "                   |                     "
    echo "      |ZZzzz      /^\            |ZZzzz  "
    echo "      |          |~~~|           |       "
    echo "      |        |-     -|        / \      "
    echo "     /^\       |[]+    |       |^^^|     "
    echo "  |^^^^^^^|    |    +[]|       |   |     "
    echo "  |    +[]|/\/\/\/\^/\/\/\/\/|^^^^^^^|   "
    echo "  |+[]+   |~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|    +[]|   "
    echo "  |       |  []   /^\   []   |+[]+   |   "
    echo "  |   +[]+|  []  || ||  []   |   +[]+|   "
    echo "  |[]+    |      || ||       |[]+    |   "
    echo "  |_______|------------------|_______|   "
    echo "                                         "
    echo "                                         "
    echo "      ${green}You have just committed code ${red}  " 
    echo "      Your code ${yellow}is bad.!!!      "
    echo "      ${red} Do not ever commit again    "
    echo "                                         "
    echo "${default}"
fi;

# set the exit code to 0 or 1 based upon your needs
# 0 = good to push
# 1 = exit without pushing.
exit 0;
```

Comment: I have found it is impossible to run hook in github server, but your answer solve it with standalone server solution. It is ok.

Comment: In github you have webhook instead

Comment: github webhook seems only call our own web url.